# How can I test HTML/CSS code before deploying to github pages

Tags: html, css, github, repository, github-pages

I know that this is possible by cloning the repository but I was wondering if this was possible to do by creating a new branch in the repository. But, If I do that then I don't know how to actually see the result of the code without deploying it publicly. If this can't be done, then how could I test the code before committing the changes.

I tried to create a new branch and committed changes to it however I couldn't figure out how to test/view the results of the code.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/changing-the-visibility-of-your-github-pages-site

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck